# C# - SQLite Storing small amount of data constantly

Tags: c#, sqlite

My Setup:

- Multi-Threaded application using Parallel.ForEach set to 40 threads.
- Adds the index of the foreach into a concurrentbag each loop.
- Once its added to the bag, it string.joins() them with , and sends it to SQLite Table.
  (It does around 14 loops/sec, sometimes more).

It works, but the CPU is unbearable. Spikes to 80-90 then goes to 10~ then back and loop. The moment I remove the .CommandText and .ExeecuteNonQueryAsync it barely goes past 4%.

**Screenshot of the CPU Usage Debug Window:**

[image: Screenshot of the CPU Usage Debug Window]

Why I do the setup above is to store the checked indexes of each loop on a hashset so that when I close, reopen and restart that loop, it knows what indexes I have already looped so that I can remove them from the hashset and continue looping without those indexes.

Is there a better way of doing what I am doing?

The code I am executing in the ForEach:

```
looper_checkedIndexes.Add(Index);
using (SQLiteCommand command = sqldb.CreateCommand()) {
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE `timeMachine` SET `indexes`='" + string.Join(",", looper_checkedIndexes) + "' WHERE `config`='" + General["name"].ToString().Replace("'", "\\'") + "'";
    command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Comment: Do the threads all have their own connection? If not, how are the DB accesses synchronized?

Comment: @CL. Not sure what you mean, the sqldb is the SQL Connection and thats basically opened and created as a var right before this code using OpenAndReturn() so that its not closing and opening every single loop pointlessly.

Comment: How many connection objects are there? One or forty?

Comment: @CL. Connections to the SQLDb? I guess one since I create the SQLConnection and open it outside and before the loop and access it from `sqldb`.

Comment: You should never use the same connection from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: @CL. What would happen exactly if I do? Wouldnt that be better no? You would open it once instead of opening 40 times closing 40 times opening 40 times (loop on avg 14 times a sec which is closing and opening 560 times a second o.o)

Comment: One connection has one transaction, so multiple statements could interfere with each other. One method to prevent conflicts is to use a lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to speed up many small writes is to combine them into a single transaction, and/or to use [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Comment: To do this I just set the journal to WAL and let it rip?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: I didnt test lmao u got me there, just questioning before I did it.

Comment: So I put WAF, and made it so its opening a connection with `using(x = x) { sqldb.Open(); }` on the using sqldb.CreateCommand code and now im getting `SQLite error (5): database is locked`, the first couple threads went through but now one, but CPU is fine (because it cant save).

Comment: If I change it so its using the pre-opened `SQLiteConnection sqldb = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=history.sqlite").OpenAndReturn();` before loop it works fine now no cpu spikes and no database locked warnings - but you mentioned this being a bad thing but its working out fine for me?

Comment: Single statements will probably be locked automatically, but you will get apparently inconsistent data if you SELECT something that another thread is changing at the same time.

Comment: Oh I think your mistaken a bit, I dont actually select anything, I only update stuff each loop, and when it is reading that data for the indexes, its when the loop hasnt even started yet.

Comment: The changing to WAL seems to have worked, but I kept using the one sqldb SqliteConnection variable as it seems to work out a LOT better